# how to delete from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

1. table `events`. In this I have fields such as
   `event_id, user_id, title, email, location, address, latitude, longitude, description, isapproved`
2. table `event_time`. In this I have fields
   `show_id, event_id, start_date, start_time, end_date, duration, date, end_time`
3. table `category`:
   `id, cat_id, event_id`

I am inserting data into 3 tables so that if an event of `event_id` 5 is entered into the `event` table then the corresponding data will be filled in `event_title` and `category`.
While filling `event_time` table if the events `start_time` is `2011-12-05` and `end_date` is `2011-12-07` then `event_time` table will filled with 3 rows like with same event id and different date:

```
show_id  event_id   start_date  start_time  end_date    duration  date          end_time
11       5          2011-12-05  12:00:00    2011-12-07  03:00:00  2011-12-07    15:00:00
10       5          2011-12-05  12:00:00    2011-12-07  03:00:00  2011-12-06    15:00:00
9        5          2011-12-05  12:00:00    2011-12-07  03:00:00  2011-12-05    15:00:00
```

The `category` table will be entered based on
number of categories selected in category drop down list.

```
id  cat_id  event_id
25  3   5
24  5   5
```

Now I want to delete the event from the database based on user choice. If he wants to delete the event of particular date then only in `event_time` it should get deleted in events, category it should be there.
But if user wants to delete event not based on any date the data from all the table should be removed.

```
<?php
include_once("webconfig.php");
include_once("webdatabase.php");
$show_id = isset($_REQUEST['show_id'])?trim($_REQUEST['show_id']):"";
$event_id = isset($_REQUEST['event_id'])?trim($_REQUEST['event_id']):"";

if(isset($show_id))
{
$s="select * from event_time where event_id='$event_id'";
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($s);
die($num_rows);
$exe=$db->query($s);
if($db->row_count()==1)
{
$sql ="Delete events,event_time,category from events join event_time join category         on(events.event_id=event_time.event_id and event_time.event_id=category.event_id) where event_time.show_id='$show_id'";
$exe=$db->query($sql);
$successMsg = "deleted Successfully! . ";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml .= '<root>';
$xml .= '<delete>';
$xml .= '<status>True</status>';
$xml .= "<message>$successMsg</message>";
$xml .= '</delete>';
$xml .= '</root>';
echo $xml;
}
else
{
$sql1 ="Delete event_time from event_time where event_time.show_id='$show_id'";
e=$db->query($sql1);
$successMsg = "deleted Successfully! . ";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml .= '<root>';
$xml .= '<delete>';
$xml .= '<status>True</status>';
$xml .= "<message>$successMsg</message>";
$xml .= '</delete>';
$xml .= '</root>';
echo $xml;
}
}
else
{
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml .= '<root>';
$xml .= '<delete>';
$xml .= '<status>false</status>';
$xml .= "<message>no data found</message>";
$xml .= '</delete>';
$xml .= '</root>';
echo $xml;
}
?>
```

this is what the code i have written.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is the database? Would that trigger a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably have to do all this in your code.  You can use triggers if your database platform supports it, and also you should look into constraints and the cascade options.

An "on delete cascade" constraint for example would automatically handle the case where you delete an event, as it would delete the related records in event_time and category for you.

The simplest solution to start with is to use code though.  So in your app, determine what needs cleaning out, and issue the deletes yourself.

To delete all time and event info for one event:

```
DELETE FROM event_time WHERE event_id = 5;
DELETE FROM event WHERE event_id = 5;
DELETE FROM category WHERE event_id = 5;
```

Or obviously to delete just the times:

```
DELETE FROM event_time WHERE show_id = 23;
```

You'll need to handle the case where there is only one time, should the event be kept in that case?  That's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Always post SQL DDL and INSERT statements for questions like this.

It's not clear whether you want to delete rows only from event_time, or from event_time and events.

To delete rows from event_time is simple.

```
delete from event_time where event_id = (?)
```

The easiest way to delete rows from both events and event_time, but leave rows in category, is to

- use a foreign key constraint on event_id in event_time,
- use ON DELETE CASCADE in that foreign key, and
- use *no* foreign key on event_id in category

After doing that, you can just delete a row from events, and the database engine will delete related rows in event_time.

```
delete from events where event_id = (?)
```

You need to use the INNODB engine to enforce foreign key constraints.

Having said all that, it looks odd to leave event_id 5 in the category table after you've deleted it from all the other tables.